# ASP.NET Core 2.0 with Telerik Kendo Grid Read method ([DataSourceRequest]) is not called in publish

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, telerik, kendo-grid, asp.net-core-2.0

I have created an application with Telerik Kendo UI and Asp.Net Core 2.0 controls. Locally we are able to run the same code without error in Visual Studio 2017, but after publishing in local IIS it gives below error(see attached image).

Error: - "http://localhost:91/Masters/GetStateList 404 (Not Found)".

[image]

While checking the error found that only Read method (may be due to '[DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest' parameter) of a grid is not called (other 
action method is perfectly called like in below code 'GetRecordStatusList()')

Controller:

```
public class MastersController : Controller
{
    private IAllRepository<StateMaster> iAllStateRepository;

    public IActionResult StateMaster()
    {
        List<SelectListItem> statusList = new List<SelectListItem>() {
            new SelectListItem{Text = "Active", Value = "1" },
            new SelectListItem{Text = "Inactive", Value = "2" }
        };

        HttpContext.Session.SetInt32("UserId", 1);
        HttpContext.Session.SetString("UserName", "Admin");
        ViewBag.UserName = HttpContext.Session.GetString("UserName");

        return View();
    }

    //This action method is not called in published-code
    public ActionResult GetStateList([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request)
    {
        this.iAllStateRepository = new StateMasterRepository();
        var result = iAllStateRepository.GetModelList();
        var dsResult = result.ToDataSourceResult(request);
        return Json(dsResult);
    }

    public JsonResult GetRecordStatusList()
    {
        List<SelectListItem> statusList = new List<SelectListItem>() {
            new SelectListItem{Text = "Active", Value = "1" },
            new SelectListItem{Text = "Inactive", Value = "2" }
        };
        return Json(statusList);
    }
}
```

**Updated** : This is View (StateMaster.cshtml) code

```
<div class="row">
     @(Html.Kendo().Grid<Entity.MasterEntity.StateMaster>()
      .Name("StateGrid")
      .Columns(columns =>
      {
       columns.Bound(p => p.StateName).Filterable(ftb => ftb.Cell(cell => cell.ShowOperators(true).Operator("contains"))).Width(120);
       columns.Bound(p => p.Abbr).Filterable(ftb => ftb.Cell(cell => cell.ShowOperators(true).Operator("contains"))).Width(120).MinScreenWidth(800);
       columns.Command(command => { command.Edit(); command.Destroy(); }).Width(70);
      })
      .ToolBar(toolbar =>
      {
       toolbar.ClientTemplateId("toolbarStatus");
      })
      .NoRecords(e => e.Template("<div class='alert alert-warning' style='padding:3px'><h6 class='bold'><i>No data found!</i></h6></div>"))
      .Pageable(p => { p.Refresh(true); p.PageSizes(true); }).Navigatable()
      .Sortable(s => s.SortMode(GridSortMode.MultipleColumn)).Scrollable(s => s.Enabled(true))

      .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:100%;" })
      .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
       .Ajax()
       .PageSize(10)
       .ServerOperation(true)
       .Model(m =>
       {
        m.Id(s => s.StateId);
        m.Field(f => f.StateName);
        m.Field(f => f.Abbr);
        m.Field(f => f.RecordStatus);
       })

       .Read(read => read.Action("GetStateList", "Masters"))

      )
      .Resizable(resize => resize.Columns(false))
     )
</div>
```

Below image is of development, which shows that the grid's read method is working properly.

[image: Working Image in development environment]

Comment: Sorry for the maybe stupid question, but you are accessing the website from localhost, not from a different one, correct? Did you map the URL (localhost) in your IIS to the correct directory? Did you try using a different URL?

Comment: I have mapped it correctly. In published code view is rendered and "GetRecordStatusList" action method is working but the action method bind with Kendo Grid Read method ("GetStateList") is not working.

Comment: @TarakPrajapati show the client side code making the request?

Comment: @Nkosi, I have updated question with the requested code. Also updated image.

Comment: Try to publish with option "Delete all existing files prior to publish"

Comment: " http://localhost:91/Masters/GetStateList " run this url in new tab. And check what exception is throwing.

Comment: @MaciejPulikowski, Sorry for the late reply. I tried to publish with the "Delete all existing files prior to publish" option. but still, the issue persists.

Answer (score 0):

I have run into a situation if areas were mapped in the routing anywhere else in the site, it would sometimes not find come controller actions.  To get around this you can clear the area by doing the following:

```
  .DataSource(s => s.Ajax().Read(read => read.Action("GetStateList", "Masters", new {area = ""})))
```

I also recommend adding the `[HttpGet]` attribute to your action. and you can force Kendo to use it by specifying the `.Type(HttpVerbs.Get)` on the read like below:

```
  .DataSource(s => s.Ajax().Read(read => read.Action("GetStateList", "Masters", new {area = ""}).Type(HttpVerbs.Get)))
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to call the Action method by changing the method to type Post by adding the [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)] just above the method.

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult GetStateList([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request)
    {
        this.iAllStateRepository = new StateMasterRepository();
        var result = iAllStateRepository.GetModelList();
        var dsResult = result.ToDataSourceResult(request);
        return Json(dsResult);
    }
```